# Populate Data on Access 2010 table using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm new to MS Access and am having a hard time trying to come up with a more efficient solution.  I have a table with a lot more data which contains something similar to the table below.

I want to be able to populate the data, which contains missing Dates (or user input).  I'm essentially trying to copy the row of the last known data into the the range of missing dates or data.  For instance, for the missing dates below (ID# 9 thru 10 or dates 1/8/2015 thru 1/9/2015), I want to copy all of the information from 1/7/2015 into the two missing dates.  I want to create a code that will search through the whole file and populate all the missing dates.

The easiest solution for me right now is to export the table into MS Excel and to manually backfill the missing dates, but this is a little time consuming.  I can write a macro and/or create a number of queries to copy a subset of tables but this seems like it would be more tedious to do and only be customized for my one table.  I tried to research for ways to do this in VBA but haven't seen a straightforward way to do it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```html
ID | DateLog | HourLog | K1_J_Int_Gen_ | K1_StationPower_Integr | K1_J_Int_Gen_Adj | 
K1_StationPower_Integr_Adj | GrossKW | AuxKW | NetKW 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 12/31/2014 | 1 | 5633.6 | 9890.4 | 5633.60009765625 | 9890.400390625  | 0 | 0    | 0 
2 | 1/1/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9898.1 | 5633.60009765625 | 9898.099609375  | 0 | 770  | -770 
3 | 1/2/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9905.7 | 5633.60009765625 | 9905.7001953125 | 0 |  760 | -760 
4 | 1/3/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9914.2 | 5633.60009765625 | 9914.2001953125 | 0 | 850  | -850 
5 | 1/4/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9922.5 | 5633.60009765625 | 9922.5          | 0 | 830  | -830 
6 | 1/5/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9932.8 | 5633.60009765625 | 9932.7998046875 | 0 | 1030 | -1030 
7 | 1/6/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9941.9 | 5633.60009765625 | 9941.900390625  | 0 | 910  | -910 
8 | 1/7/2015   | 1 | 5633.6 | 9950.4 | 5633.60009765625 | 9950.400390625  | 0 | 850  | -850 
11 | 1/10/2015 | 1 | 5633.6 | 9974.7 | 5633.60009765625 | 9974.7001953125 | 0 | 0    | 0 
12 | 1/11/2015 | 1 | 5633.6 | 9983.1 | 5633.60009765625 | 9983.099609375  | 0 | 840  | -840 
13 | 1/12/2015 | 1 | 5633.6 | 9991   | 5633.60009765625 | 9991            | 0 | 790  | -790 
14 | 1/13/2015 | 1 | 5633.6 | 9998.5 | 5633.60009765625 | 9998.5          | 0 | 750  | -750​
```

Comment: If you narrow down your question to particular issues you come across while developing this system you will get better results. Generally when people read "How do I make this system?" type questions, they will just skip right over it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to be more specific next time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method here to locate and fill in the gaps: [Fill in missing date gaps in Access table](http://rdsrc.us/5BiQeL)

You can easily modify it to copy the fields you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Attempted the suggestion and got the error, see above.